# Is it a good idea to edit the spam away instead of waiting for enough flags to be raised?

Tags: support

The aim of this question is to understand what the system prefers.

On Aviation it often happens that spam messages end up in the LQ queue and thus end up being "reccommended for deletion" but not flagged as spam. They end up deleted, but not recognized as spam from the system.

As a consequence, some users have started to edit away the spammy posts while they are in the queue.

Is this a good idea? I.e., does the spam prevention system like this? Or should we somehow prod more users into flagging the posts instead?